# Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M (keyboard shortcut) not working as expected (VS-2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I use `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M` to collapse/expand modules in the `text editor`.

But since the last few days, it shows weird behaviour. I do not know how to grammatically describe the problem, hence I have not been able to google out a solution.

Pics are attached. How can I make it normal again?
***Edit: How can I reset the vs-editor to default values (If there is such a thing)?***

Thanks

[image: Problem 1]
[image: Problem 2]

Comment: Just tried it on my VS2017 (Windows 10) and it works fine.

Comment: It used to work for me before too. It has just started a few days back! Is there any way I can reset the vs editor to default values?

Comment: VS2017 has a repair functionality in the VS installer. I think VS2015 does too, though I don't remember. Perhaps in "uninstall programs" in the Control Panel. But keep in mind that this can take a long time. Also, if the problem is in some temporary file, I'm not sure it'll be solved. How about if you create a new project, does it work there?

Comment: Hi @ispiro. You are right, other solutions work fine. The problem is only with this particular solution. I guess I will have to live with it for now. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: You can try deleting the `.vs` folder (it's a hidden folder in the same folder as your `yourSolution.sln` file). I would, though, just rename it, so you can rename it again to `.vs` if things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options>Environment>Keyboard

Press the reset button [step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwDvy.png)

Secondly from the keyboard mapping scheme choose Visual C# 2005 [step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsDhB.png)

Alternatevly if this does not work press CTRL+M,CTRL+O and then press CTRL+M,CTRL+L and then try using CTRL+M,CTRL+M

Hope this helps